# Not able to Sort Correctly for some reason using EPOCH in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here's my Create Table :

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPSORT_TABLE 
(SortRowID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
SortTitle TEXT NOT NULL, 
SortPrice INTEGER NOT NULL, 
SortDateTime datetime default (('2000-01-01')), 
SortTrueDateTime INTEGER NOT NULL)
```

I have created a simple Table and I have a column called "`SortTrueDateTime`" is an **INTEGER** column and it stores a successfully converted Date that was converted to **EPOCH** time. Now for SOME unknown reason when I do a simple..

```
SELECT SortTrueDateTime FROM TEMPSORT_TABLE ORDER BY SortTrueDateTime DESC
```

It isn't actually sorting correctly by the `SortTrueDateTime` column... they are just still random records...

ANY one have this crazy issue or able to assist me in any way to try and accomplish my goal?

EXAMPLE output..

```
1418878800000
1388638800000
1419224400000
1388638800000
1419224400000
```

Comment: Add some log output from that SELECT statement so that we can see what the values look like.

Comment: A `select *` statement should return five columns, not one. Is this your actual output?

Comment: Yes this is my actual output i just copied down the columns results... i updated my line and reseted it by not including any other columns.... not an idiot lol